# Why is ASP.NET inserting "�����" into output HTML?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm working with two ASP.NET (.NET 4.5, IIS 10.0.17763.1) projects. Both are affected by this problem. There are dozens other projects built using the same technology that are working fine.

When debugging, "e" followed by precisely 2050 "�" symbols are inserted into the output html in seemingly random places. There doesn't seem to be any pattern to where they show up.

How it looks like when I hit "Inspect" in Chrome:

```
<img id="cphHomeBannerMe���������[...]����������ain_ScrollingBanner1_firstImage"
```

"View page source":

```
type="text/css" media="screen" /e  [multiline blank space]     ><link href=
```

When I copy the output of "View page source" into notepad, the blank space is removed but "e" remains. So, for the above example it would be

```
type="text/css" media="screen" /e><link href=
```

Needless to say, it completely breaks the page layout.

Launching without debugging (ctrl+f5) launches the project normally.
The project is version controlled using TFS and runs well on other PCs.

Comment: I'm afraid that we'll need a [mcve] to solve this mystery. Since you say that *"[t]here are dozens other projects built using the same technology that are working fine."*, creating such a [mcve] should be possible.

Comment: I can't see a way for me to construct the example, I'm affraid. I don't know how to replicate the issue. I don't even know which part of the project causes the problem. Even attaching the entire project wouldn't help as it works on most other machines. Any suggestions welcome, of course!

Comment: Keep removing things from your project until either it starts working, or you end up with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by unchecking `Enable Browser Link` and reloading the page. The option should be under a menu that has a little refresh icon as it's image - next to the debug dropdown in your toolbar.

If you want to know more, see: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 
Sadly, it was already unchecked. When I hover over the refresh button, the tooltip says Browser Link - No browsers connected. I also don't have the browser link in the code of the running site. It doesn't look like that's the cause of the issue.

Comment: Oh well, sorry it didn't work. I'll leave the comment up in case it works for someone else. Cheers.